Perturbation to a Dirac delta potential well
I am considering an unperturbed Hamiltonian of the form:
$$H_0 \equiv -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} - \alpha\, \delta(x),$$
which has a single bound state solution given by $$\psi^{(0)}(x) = \sqrt{\dfrac{m\alpha}{\hbar}} \exp\left(-\dfrac{m\alpha}{\hbar^2} |x|\right),$$ with energy eigenvalue $$E^{(0)} = -\dfrac{m\alpha^2}{2\hbar^2}.$$
Now, I introduce a sinusoidal perturbation to this system: $$H' = a\,\sin(kx).$$
The first-order energy correction is straightforward to compute:
$$E^{(1)} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi^{(0)*}(x) \, H'(x) \, \psi^{(0)}(x) \, dx = -\frac{ma\alpha}{\hbar^2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left(-\dfrac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^2} |x|\right) \sin(kx) \, dx = 0.$$
However, when I try to compute the second-order energy correction,
$$E^{(2)}_n = \sum_{k \neq n} \dfrac{\left|\langle k^{(0)} | H' | n^{(0)} \rangle \right|^2}{E_n^{(0)} - E_k^{(0)}},$$
I encounter a problem. In this system, there is only one energy eigenvalue and eigenstate for the bound state. Thus, it seems that the second-order correction, and similarly the third-order and higher-order corrections, cannot be computed.
So my questions are:

Is it true that there are no second-order or higher-order corrections to the eigenstate and energy in this case?

If so, since the first-order energy correction $E^{(1)}$ vanishes, does this mean the spectrum of $H_0$ and $H_0 + H'$ remains completely identical? How can this be interpreted physically?



In "simple" one-dimensional cases like this, one can often solve the first-order Schrödinger equation analytically:
$$
\Big[H^{(0)}-E^{(0)}\Big]|\psi^{(1)}\rangle=-\Big[W-E^{(1)}\Big]|\psi^{(0)}\rangle
$$
as an inhomogeneous differential equation to find the exact first-order wave function. Then the second- and third-order energies can be readily computed, and the pain of dealing with scattering states is avoided, because not a single sum-over-states appears in our perturbation formulae.
To keep things simple, I start with natural units $\hbar=c=1$, so that
$$
H=-\frac{1}{2m}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} x^2}-\alpha\delta(x)+a\sin(kx) \ ,
$$
where $\delta(x)$ has dimension $1/\text{length}=\text{energy}$, so $\alpha$ is dimensionless. Let us introduce the energy and length scales
$$
{\cal{E}}_0=m\alpha^2 \ \ \ , \ \ \ l_0=\frac{1}{m\alpha} \ .
$$
Then the dimensionless problem reads
$$
{\cal{H}}=\frac{1}{{\cal{E}}_0}H=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} {x'}^2}-\delta(x')+q\sin(\kappa x') \ ,
$$
where $q=a/{\cal{E}}_0$, $\kappa=kl_0$ and $x'=x/l_0$ (but I will name it as $x$ from now on for simplicity). The zeroth-order solution is just
$$
\psi^{(0)}(x)=\exp(-|x|) \ \ , \ \ E^{{(0)}}=-\frac{1}{2} \ ,
$$
and $E^{{(1)}}=0$. The first-order Schrödinger equation reads
$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} x^2}-\delta(x)+\frac{1}{2}\right]\psi^{(1)}(x)=-q\sin(\kappa x)\exp(-|x|) \ .
$$
Since $\psi^{(0)}(x)$ is even and the perturbation is odd, we expect from symmetry considerations that $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ is odd. This means $\psi^{(1)}(0)=0$, so the delta function term can be dropped:
$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right]\psi^{(1)}(x)=-q\sin(\kappa x)\exp(-|x|) \ .
$$
The well-behaving solution for $x>0$ is
$$
\psi^{(1)}_+(x)=c_+\exp(-x)+\frac{2q}{\kappa(4+\kappa^2)}\Big[2\cos(\kappa x)-\kappa\sin(\kappa x)\Big]\exp(-x) \ ,
$$
and for $x<0$, it is
$$
\psi^{(1)}_-(x)=c_-\exp(+x)-\frac{2q}{\kappa(4+\kappa^2)}\Big[2\cos(\kappa x)+\kappa\sin(\kappa x)\Big]\exp(+x) \ .
$$
Matching the two solutions as $x\rightarrow0$ leads to the relation
$$
c_+-c_-=-\frac{8q}{\kappa(4+\kappa^2)} \ .
$$
We need one more condition to completely fix the first-order wave function, the intermediate normalization:
$$
\langle\psi^{(0)}|\psi^{(1)}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^0\mathrm{d}x\psi^{(0)}(x)\psi^{(1)}_-(x)+\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x\psi^{(0)}(x)\psi^{(1)}_+(x)=0 \ .
$$
After carrying out the integrals, we find $c_++c_-=0$ from this condition, so
$$
c_\pm=\mp\frac{4q}{\kappa(4+\kappa^2)} \ ,
$$
and $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ is completely determined:
$$
\psi^{(1)}(x)=-\frac{2q}{4+\kappa^2}\text{sgn}(x)\left[2\frac{1-\cos(\kappa x)}{\kappa}+\sin(\kappa |x|)\right]\exp(-|x|) \ .
$$
The solution has odd parity and vanishes at $x=0$, as expected.
The second-order energy is then
$$
E^{(2)}=\langle\psi^{(0)}|W|\psi^{(1)}\rangle=-\frac{\kappa^2(10+\kappa^2)}{(1+\kappa^2)(4+\kappa^2)^2}q^2 \ ,
$$
manifestly negative, as all second-order corrections to ground state energies should be. Because of the $2n+1$ theorem of Wigner, knowing $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ would be sufficient to determine the third-order energy as well:
$$ 
E^{(3)}=\langle\psi^{(1)}|W|\psi^{(1)}\rangle-E^{(1)}\langle\psi^{(1)}|\psi^{(1)}\rangle \ ,
$$
but this is of course zero due to parity reasons, just like $E^{(1)}$ was.
So in conclusion, the energy of the perturbed system seems to be
$$
E=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\kappa^2(10+\kappa^2)}{(1+\kappa^2)(4+\kappa^2)^2}q^2+{\cal{O}}(q^4) \ .
$$
This system is very special because the unperturbed Hamiltonian has only a single bound state, so all perturbation contributions come from the continuum part of the zeroth-order spectrum. But actually, continuum states are always important in perturbation theory, even if one has an infinite number of zeroth-order bound states (like in the case of the hydrogen atom). I prepared some examples of this (probably surprising) phenomenon in an earlier answer.

When you say “first order Schrodinger equation” do you mean $\psi(x)=\psi^{(0)}+q \psi^{(1)}$ expanded in powers of $q$?

@ZeroTheHero We expand both $\psi_n$ and $E_n$ in the Schr. eq., and then separate the powers to get independent equations like
$$
(H^{0}-E_n^{(0)})\psi_n^{(0)}=0
$$
$$
(H^{0}-E_n^{(0)})\psi_n^{(1)}+(W-E_n^{(1)})\psi_n^{(0)}=0
$$
$$
(H^{0}-E_n^{(0)})\psi_n^{(2)}+(W-E_n^{(1)})\psi_n^{(1)}-E_n^{(2)}\psi_n^{(0)}=0
$$
and so on. These are what I call $k$-th order Schrodinger equations. We usually solve these by inverting $H^{0}-E_n^{(0)}$ in the subspace orthogonal to $\psi_n^{(0)}$, but this means a basis set expansion over the zeroth-order spectrum, and now we don't want that.

@ZeroTheHero Or maybe the question was about the expansion parameter? Yes, we expand in powers of the dimensionless parameter $q=a/{\cal{E}}_0$. This is the ratio of the characteristic energy scales of the perturbation and the zeroth-order problem, and it should be small by assumption.


It is not true. The expression that you are using for higher corrections of the energy levels include the corrections in the eigenstate $\psi^{(0)}$, which in turn is obtained using a resolution of identity . In other words, the expression that you are using only makes sense if you know all unperturbed eigenstates of the unperturbed Hamiltonian, such a way that they form a complete basis, i.e., $\int dk \left|k^{(0)}\right \rangle\!\left \langle k^{(0)}\right| = \mathbb I$. You could read more in the wiki.

The thing is that there is only one bound eigenstate, so it is not a complete basis, then you should include the unbounded eigenstates to complete the basis.  It makes sense, since you should take into account that the perturbation could induce a transition of bounded to unbounded state, setting free the particle.
I would recommend you to calculate the correction $\psi^{(1)}$ first, before going into $E^{(2)}$.
I would also recommend the reference [1] for a review about Delta Potentials and the completeness relation, and its use in perturbation theory (with different potential, but you could take notes).

[1] The infinite well and Dirac delta function potentials as pedagogical, mathematical and physical models in quantum mechanics chapter 6.3

The same problem arises in $\psi^{(1)}$ also. The denominator in the general expression of $\psi^{(1)}$ can not be evaluated as there is only one bound state.

Right, so you should take into account unbounded eigenstates of your unperturbed Hamiltonian

You could find in this reference https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/delta-potential a reasonable discussion about completeness of bound and unbounded states with Delta potentials and references therein
